# How to use map to get an array of objects from a parent array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't get the expected output with this. I've tried variants but no use. What is the right way to do it?

```js
var itemsdata = [{
    "id": "item1",
    "assets": [{
      "id": "size",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "id": "age",
      "value": 14
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "item2",
    "assets": [{
      "id": "size",
      "value": 1
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "item13",
    "assets": [{
      "id": "size",
      "value": 1
    }]
  }
];

var itemid = 'item1';

var itemassets = itemsdata.map(d => d.id === itemid ? d.assets : '');

console.log(itemassets);
//expected output: [{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]
```

Comment: Your code is fine you can remove the else condition -> `d.assets : ''` inside the map to get the desired result.

Comment: I will get an error if I do that.

Comment: No use like `if( )`

Comment: could you please post the full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the empty strings with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the empty strings:

```
var itemassets = itemsdata.map(d => d.id === itemid ? d.assets : '').filter(d => d !== '');
```

Full example (using `null` instead of an empty string):

```js
var itemsdata = [{ "id": "item1", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }, { "id": "age", "value": 14 }] }, { "id": "item2", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }] }, { "id": "item13", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }] } ];
var itemid = 'item1';

var itemassets = itemsdata.filter(d => d.id === itemid).map(d => d.assets);

console.log(itemassets[0]); //expected output: [{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]
```

The first `filter` iterates over your array and only returns the matched items, then the map returns the desired `assets` attribute.

This will produce an array of arrays, and you only need to print the first item of it.

---

Or as a different approach:

```js
var itemsdata = [{ "id": "item1", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }, { "id": "age", "value": 14 }] }, { "id": "item2", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }] }, { "id": "item13", "assets": [{ "id": "size", "value": 1 }] }, { "id": "item99", "assets": [] } ];

var itemid = 'item1';

var itemassets = itemsdata.filter(d => d.id === itemid && d.assets).reduce((acc, d) => [...acc, ...d.assets], []);

console.log(itemassets); //expected output: [{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]
```

With [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you combine your results in one array

Comment: Thanks, reduce is what I was looking for. Just one thing. If the item happens to have null in assets lets say `{"id":"item8", "assets":null}` I get an error. How can I fix that?

Comment: I updated my second example with `itemsdata.filter(d => d.id === itemid && d.assets).reduce((acc, d) => [...acc, ...d.assets], []);`, the part with `&& d.assets` means that `d.assets` is truthy: Not null, and not an empty array

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine you just need to remove the `else` case.

```js
var itemsdata = [
  {"id":"item1", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]},
  {"id":"item2", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]},
  {"id":"item13", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]}
 ];

var itemid = 'item1';
var itemassets;
itemsdata.forEach((e)=>{
  if(e.id===itemid){
    itemassets = e.assets
  }
})

console.log(itemassets);
```

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Thats a good approach too. Thank you.

Comment: `map` is the wrong method to use for this. The callback for `map` should return a transformed element. You'd be better off with `forEach` or even a `for...of` loop.

Comment: this will not take all the items assets if there are items with the same id

Comment: Yes, I will change that, didn't notice.

Comment: @AhmedSbai Ideally ids are meant to be _unique_ - that's what makes them ids in the first place. If there are duplicate ids that's a data problem. And even so `map` would still be the wrong method. You'd want to use `filter`.

Comment: you are right already in my answer i used  ForEach but i want it to be correct for all cases

Answer (score 1):

`map` will calls a function on *all* array elements. If the ids are unique you most likely need [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to iterate through the array until it finds an object with an `id` that matches your query, and return its `assets` array.

This function returns the assets array if the object is found, a message that the object has no assets if `assets` is `null`, or a message to say that the object was not found if it doesn't exist in the array.

```js
const arr=[{id:"item1",assets:[{id:"size",value:1},{id:"age",value:14}]},{id:"item2",assets:[{id:"size",value:1}]},{id:"item13",assets:[{id:"size",value:1}]},{"id":"item8", "assets":null}];

function assetsById(arr, query) {
  const found = arr.find(obj => obj.id === query);
  if (found) return found.assets || 'No assets';
  return 'Object not found';
}

console.log(assetsById(arr, 'item1'));
console.log(assetsById(arr, 'item5'));
console.log(assetsById(arr, 'item8'));
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
let itemassets = []
itemsdata.forEach(d => {
    if(d.id === itemid && d.assets) {
        d.assets.forEach(a =>{
            itemassets.push(a)
        })
    } ; 
})
console.log(itemassets)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to select only a particular array entry, you should be using find and not filter.

```js
const itemsdata = [{"id":"item1","assets":[{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]},{"id":"item2","assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]},{"id":"item13","assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]}]

console.log(itemsdata.find(({id})=>id==='item1')?.assets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "filter(...)" to achieve a similar result...

```
var itemsdata = [
    {"id":"item1", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1},{"id":"age","value":14}]},
    {"id":"item2", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]},
    {"id":"item3", "assets":[{"id":"size","value":1}]}
];

var itemid = 'item1';

let [ itemassets ] = itemsdata.filter(i => i.id === itemid);

// if the data do not exist will return undefined
itemassets = itemassets?.assets;

// result [ { id: 'size', value: 1 }, { id: 'age', value: 14 } ];
console.log(itemassets);
```